# React Navigation goes to initial route while navigating

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux, react-redux, react-navigation

I use expo, redux and react navigation.

The following is my initial route **Preloader.js**

```
    class PreloaderScreen extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        console.log("CWM --", this.props.auth);
        this.props.getLocalToken();
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        console.log("NXT props - PL", nextProps);
        if (nextProps.auth.localTokenStatus == 1) {
            console.log("Navigating to main");
            this.props.navigation.navigate('Main');
        }
        else if (nextProps.auth.localTokenStatus == -1) {
            console.log("Navigating to Login !!!!");
            this.props.navigation.navigate('Login');
        }
        else {
            console.log("Nothing is happening !");
        }

    }

    render() {
        const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
        return (
            <View>
            </View>
        )

    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        auth: state.auth,
    };
}
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return bindActionCreators({ getLocalToken: getLocalToken, storeLocalToken: storeLocalToken }, dispatch)
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(PreloaderScreen)
```

I check for an AsyncStorage variable on this page and redirect accordingly. I check the AsyncStorage in the following AuthAction.

```
export function getLocalTokenSuccess(localStore) {
    console.log('Got Local Token', localStore);
    return {
        type: types.GET_LOCALTOKEN_SUCCESS,
        payload: localStore
    }

}

export function getLocalTokenFail(error) {
    return {
        type: types.GET_LOCALTOKEN_FAIL
    }
}


export const getLocalToken = (dispatch) => {
    return (dispatch) => {

        AsyncStorage.getItem('localToken')
            .then((localStore) => dispatch(getLocalTokenSuccess(localStore)))
            .catch((error) => dispatch(getLocalTokenFail(error)))
    }
}
```

The following is my reducer, **reducer-auth.js**

```
case types.GET_LOCALTOKEN_SUCCESS:
      localTokenJSON = JSON.parse(action.payload);
      console.log("localStore ", action.payload);
      return { ...state, key: localTokenJSON.key, mobileNumber: localTokenJSON.mobileNumber, localTokenStatus: 1 };
      break;

    case types.GET_LOCALTOKEN_FAIL:
      console.log("gltf --");
      return { ...state, localTokenStatus: -1 }
      break;
```

Following is my **Login.js** where I land if there's no local token found.

```
class LoginScreen extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

  }

  submitButton(isValid) {
    return (
      <Button backgroundColor='#0000b2' style={LoginStyle.buttonStyle}
        onPress={() => { console.log("Pressed"); this.props.submitOTPMobileNumber(this.props.auth.mobileNumber) }}
        disabled={!isValid}
        title='Login' />
    );
  }

  state = {
    keyboardHeight: new Animated.Value(0)
  };

  animateKeyboardHeight = (toValue, duration) => {
    Animated.timing(
      this.state.keyboardHeight,
      { toValue, duration },
    ).start();
  };

  componentWillMount() {

    if (Platform.OS === "android") {
      this.keyboardShowListener = Keyboard.addListener("keyboardDidShow", ({ endCoordinates }) => {
        this.animateKeyboardHeight(endCoordinates.height, 0)
      });
      this.keyboardHideListener = Keyboard.addListener("keyboardDidHide", () => {
        this.animateKeyboardHeight(0, 300)
      })

    }
  }
  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (nextProps.auth.OTPAPISubmissionSuccess)
      this.props.navigation.navigate('Otp');
  }

  scrollToInput = (reactNode) => {
    this.view.scrollToFocusedInput(reactNode)
  };

  handleOnFocus = (e) => {
    if (Platform.OS === "android") {
      this.scrollToInput(ReactNative.findNodeHandle(e.target))
    }
  };

  render() {

    const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
    return (
      <KeyboardAwareScrollView
        ref={ref => this.view = ref}
        enableOnAndroid
        extraHeight={Platform.OS === "android" ? 10 : undefined}
      >
        <View>
          <Image style={LoginStyle.backgroundImage} source={require('../Images/Icons/login.jpeg')} />
        </View>
        <Card style={LoginStyle.loginBox}>
          <Text style={LoginStyle.subtitle}>India (+91)</Text>
          <TextInput
            onFocus={this.handleOnFocus}
            style={LoginStyle.textInput}
            keyboardType='numeric'
            placeholder="Mobile Number"
            maxLength={10} minLength={10}
            onChangeText={(mobileNumber) => { this.props.OTPMobileNumberEntered(mobileNumber) }}
            value={this.props.auth.mobileNumber}>
          </TextInput>
          <Text>{"\n"}</Text>
          <Text style={LoginStyle.subText}>We will send you a one time SMS message</Text>
          <Text>{"\n"}</Text>
          {this.submitButton(this.props.auth.mobileIsValid)}
        </Card>
        <Animated.View style={{ height: this.state.keyboardHeight }} />

      </KeyboardAwareScrollView>

    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    auth: state.auth,
  };
}
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return bindActionCreators({
    OTPMobileNumberEntered: OTPMobileNumberEntered,
    submitOTPMobileNumber: submitOTPMobileNumber,
  }, dispatch)
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(LoginScreen)
```

But when I run this code. The app navigates like this 
**Preloader** > finding no localtoken goes to **Login** > On submit of phone number it goes to **Preloader** > then **Login** > then finally **OTP**

Why won't it navigate directly to **OTP** without going to **Preloader** page?

Following is the log on the expo console

```
FB Initialized
21:23:51
CWM -- Object {
  "OTPAPISubmissionSuccess": false,
  "OTPIsValid": true,
  "OTPNumber": "9000",
  "firebaseToken": "",
  "key": "",
  "localToken": "",
  "localTokenStatus": 0,
  "loginSuccess": 0,
  "mobileIsValid": true,
  "mobileNumber": "8891468710",
  "store": "",
  "user": "",
}
21:23:51
Got Local Token null
21:23:51
localStore  null
21:23:51
gltf --
21:23:51
NXT props - PL Object {
  "auth": Object {
    "OTPAPISubmissionSuccess": false,
    "OTPIsValid": true,
    "OTPNumber": "9000",
    "firebaseToken": "",
    "key": "",
    "localToken": "",
    "localTokenStatus": -1,
    "loginSuccess": 0,
    "mobileIsValid": true,
    "mobileNumber": "8891468710",
    "store": "",
    "user": "",
  },
  "getLocalToken": [Function anonymous],
  "navigation": Object {
    "dispatch": [Function anonymous],
    "goBack": [Function goBack],
    "navigate": [Function navigate],
    "setParams": [Function setParams],
    "state": Object {
      "key": "Init-id-1507132425968-0",
      "routeName": "Preloader",
    },
  },
  "screenProps": undefined,
  "storeLocalToken": [Function anonymous],
}
21:23:51
Navigating to Login !!!!
21:23:51
Navigation Dispatch:
21:23:51
Action:  Object {
  "action": undefined,
  "params": undefined,
  "routeName": "Login",
  "type": "Navigation/NAVIGATE",
}
21:23:51
New State:  Object {
  "index": 1,
  "routes": Array [
    Object {
      "key": "Init-id-1507132425968-0",
      "routeName": "Preloader",
    },
    Object {
      "key": "id-1507132425968-1",
      "params": undefined,
      "routeName": "Login",
    },
  ],
}
21:23:51
Last State:  Object {
  "index": 0,
  "routes": Array [
    Object {
      "key": "Init-id-1507132425968-0",
      "routeName": "Preloader",
    },
  ],
}
21:23:51
21:34:09
Pressed
21:34:09
HTTP request =>  8891468710
21:34:09
Requesting HTTP
21:34:09
HTTP response, Object {
  "message": "OTP sent successfully",
  "status": "OK",
}
21:34:09
checkOTPAPIStatus OK
21:34:09
checkOTPAPIStatus OK
21:34:09
OTP SEND -- Reducer !
21:34:09
NXT props - PL Object {
  "auth": Object {
    "OTPAPISubmissionSuccess": true,
    "OTPIsValid": true,
    "OTPNumber": "9000",
    "firebaseToken": "",
    "key": "",
    "localToken": "",
    "localTokenStatus": -1,
    "loginSuccess": 0,
    "mobileIsValid": true,
    "mobileNumber": "8891468710",
    "store": "",
    "user": "",
  },
  "getLocalToken": [Function anonymous],
  "navigation": Object {
    "dispatch": [Function anonymous],
    "goBack": [Function goBack],
    "navigate": [Function navigate],
    "setParams": [Function setParams],
    "state": Object {
      "key": "Init-id-1507132425968-0",
      "routeName": "Preloader",
    },
  },
  "screenProps": undefined,
  "storeLocalToken": [Function anonymous],
}
21:34:09
Navigating to Login !!!!
21:34:09
Navigation Dispatch:
21:34:09
Action:  Object {
  "action": undefined,
  "params": undefined,
  "routeName": "Login",
  "type": "Navigation/NAVIGATE",
}
21:34:09
New State:  Object {
  "index": 2,
  "routes": Array [
    Object {
      "key": "Init-id-1507132425968-0",
      "routeName": "Preloader",
    },
    Object {
      "key": "id-1507132425968-1",
      "params": undefined,
      "routeName": "Login",
    },
    Object {
      "key": "id-1507132425968-2",
      "params": undefined,
      "routeName": "Login",
    },
  ],
}
21:34:09
Last State:  Object {
  "index": 1,
  "routes": Array [
    Object {
      "key": "Init-id-1507132425968-0",
      "routeName": "Preloader",
    },
    Object {
      "key": "id-1507132425968-1",
      "params": undefined,
      "routeName": "Login",
    },
  ],
}
21:34:09
21:34:09
Navigation Dispatch:
21:34:09
Action:  Object {
  "action": undefined,
  "params": undefined,
  "routeName": "Otp",
  "type": "Navigation/NAVIGATE",
}
21:34:09
New State:  Object {
  "index": 3,
  "routes": Array [
    Object {
      "key": "Init-id-1507132425968-0",
      "routeName": "Preloader",
    },
    Object {
      "key": "id-1507132425968-1",
      "params": undefined,
      "routeName": "Login",
    },
    Object {
      "key": "id-1507132425968-2",
      "params": undefined,
      "routeName": "Login",
    },
    Object {
      "key": "id-1507132425968-3",
      "params": undefined,
      "routeName": "Otp",
    },
  ],
}
21:34:09
Last State:  Object {
  "index": 2,
  "routes": Array [
    Object {
      "key": "Init-id-1507132425968-0",
      "routeName": "Preloader",
    },
    Object {
      "key": "id-1507132425968-1",
      "params": undefined,
      "routeName": "Login",
    },
    Object {
      "key": "id-1507132425968-2",
      "params": undefined,
      "routeName": "Login",
    },
  ],
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you're changing the props recieved by the Preloader (the navigation props), so you'll enter it's "ComponentWillRecieveProps", which will trigger the navigation to Login, you can fix this with:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
            if(this.props.auth.localTokenStatus!=nextProps.auth.localTokenStatus){
               console.log("NXT props - PL", nextProps);
               if (nextProps.auth.localTokenStatus == 1) {
                   console.log("Navigating to main");
                   this.props.navigation.navigate('Main');
               }
               else if (nextProps.auth.localTokenStatus == -1) {
                   console.log("Navigating to Login !!!!");
                   this.props.navigation.navigate('Login');
               }
               else {
                console.log("Nothing is happening !");
               }
            }
        }
```

Which compares if the nextProps.localTokenStatus is different from your this.props.localTokenStatus before triggering the navigation again, so it won't happen unless the localTokenStatus from your redux changes.

EDIT:
This happens because preloader still exists since you didn't clear it's stack from the navigation, you can do so with this function:

```
import { NavigationActions } from 'react-navigation';
...
clearStack(route) {
    const resetAction = NavigationActions.reset({
      index: 0,
      actions: [
        NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: route})
      ]
    })
    this.props.navigation.dispatch(resetAction)
  }
```

Which can be called where you're calling "this.props.navigate('routeName')" in the preloader

Comment: Why preloader gets called when I navigate from Login to OTP page?

Comment: Check my EDIT, since i don't know how to write code in comments yet. If it's helpful please remember to upvote/flag as best answer

Comment: Sure!, So I've to do this every time I navigate from screen to screen?

Comment: If you don't want the user to be able to go back to the previous screens, yes you should.

Comment: I don't have a problem with the user going back to the previous screen. I've a problem with it when I navigate from screen B to C it goes to the screen A and then B and C.

Comment: But this is only happening on your Preloader cause it navigates based on props changes, which happens when the navigation changes, so you probably wont have this problem in other screens